# ActiveMQ 5.8 network of broker with custom jmx port

Tags: activemq-classic, ubuntu-12.04, jmx

I am trying to run a network of broker with 2 brokers on the same network but on 2 different virtual machines.

Because of some internal constraints I have to use a custom jmx port.
I am using the Tanuki wrapper to launch ActiveMQ on an Ubuntu server.

Here is the relevant part of my activemq.xml

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" advisorySupport="false" useJmx="true" brokerName="test1" dataDirectory=".../data/activemq">
    <networkConnectors>
        <networkConnector uri="multicast://1.2.3.4:101234?group=test" 
            dynamicOnly="true"
            networkTTL="3"
            prefetchSize="1"
            decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true" 
            userName="user"
            password="password"/>
    </networkConnectors>

    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"  rebalanceClusterClients="true" updateClusterClients="true" />
        <transportConnector name="nio" uri="nio://0.0.0.0:61617"  rebalanceClusterClients="true" updateClusterClients="true" discoveryUri="multicast://1.2.3.4:101234?group=test"  />
    </transportConnectors>
    ...
    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>
    ...
</broker>
```

Here is the relevant part of wrapper.conf:

```
# Uncomment to enable jmx
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4321
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

When running ActiveMQ on both broker, I see the process with the expected options:

> activemq 30682 30680  3 13:27 ?        00:00:30 java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4321 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=../../conf/broker.ks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=../../conf/broker.ts -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Dactivemq.conf=../../conf -Dactivemq.data=../../data -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Djava.library.path=../../bin/linux-x86-64/ -classpath ../../bin/wrapper.jar:../../bin/activemq.jar -Dwrapper.key=y4TuwO32Hj6kN7w8 -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=30680 -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3 -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.service=TRUE -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.apache.activemq.console.Main start

The port is open on the running shorewall.

The network of broker is up but I cannot connect to the jmx using jvisualvm with server_dns:4321. It returns the error 
"cannot connect to server_dns:4321 using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://server_dns:4321/jmxrmi

I can see some traffic on the port via tcpdump.

Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong or how I should use ActiveMQ as a Network Of Broker with a custom jmx port?

Comment: when I check the port in use I see that 2 jmx ports are listen by activemq. It listen to the custom 4321 and the standard 1099. When setting useJmx to false in activemq.xml I see that only the custom port is still in use. But still I cannot connect to it.
I have heard that Network Of Brokers are also using the JMX interface to communicate. How can I see the port that is really used by the 2 brokers?

Comment: By reading again the network of broker documentation I figured out that I wrongly configured it. I made each of my 2 brokers both a master/slave and a node in the network of broker. This network cannot work because one of the 2 nodes will always be slave and thus not active at any time. But still after dropping the network part I cannot connect to the JMX. I am now trying to set 2 master/slave pairs in one network of broker. I'll post my observation if relevant afterwards

Comment: I finally made the change not to have 2 running nodes in my network of brokers (2 pairs of master slave, each of them being a node in the network).
Unfortunately this didn't help on enabling the connection to the JMX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMX needs 2 open ports. An extra one is necessary for rmi.
I figured it out thanks to this post: [Apache ActiveMQ browser can't connect to JMX console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093003/apache-activemq-browser-cant-connect-to-jmx-console)

In my case the fix is to change the configuration of my wrapper to expose the rmi port and open the port on the firewall

```
# Uncomment to enable jmx
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4321
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8765
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```