# ActiveMQ Browser V2.5.2.8 can't connect to ActiveMQ V5.12.1

Tags: activemq-classic

I tried to connect to ActiveMQ V5.12.1 with ActiveMQ Browser V2.5.2.8, they are installed on the same computer. but failed.
ActiveMQ Browser always complaining
/*
Could not start QBrowserV2
Failed to connect to ActiveMQ JMX Server.
*/
I followed its instruction to use Jms=true on broker elment of activemq.xml,
also set connectorPort="10000", rmiServerPort="10001" on managementContext element.
I left other configuations default and restart activemq by double clicking the activemq.bat file which located under ACTIVEMQ_HOME\bin\win64

but still no luck.

Meanwhile, I noticed that i can use jconsole to connect ActiveMQ successfully.
Anyone had met same problems? What I want to use ActiveMQ Browser is to monitor the incoming messages, when it is not consumed by subscriber and is in dispatched queue, I want to extract the concrete message contents.

I checked the question, but it is Activemq 5.8.0.
[Apache ActiveMQ browser can't connect to JMX console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093003/apache-activemq-browser-cant-connect-to-jmx-console)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem now with ActiveMQ 5.13.4 and my problem was that I didn't copy the correct activemq jar files to AvtiveMQBrowser folder.

https://sourceforge.net/p/activemqbrowser/discussion/962581/thread/464131a8/#0ce4

1. Copy `activemq-all-<version>.jar` from the `<installation folder>` of ActiveMQ broker to `ActiveMQBrowser_<version>` folder.
2. Copy `activemq-web-<version>.jar` from the `<installation folder>/lib` of ActiveMQ broker to `ActiveMQBrowser_<version>` folder.
3. Update `run_activemq_browser.bat` with paths to the correct activeMQ jar files including correct version number.

The above steps allowed me to connect.